# how does qtDebug() syntax work

Tags: c++, qt

This is the alternate syntax for qDebug() provided in the qt Documentation.

> qDebug() << "Brush:" << myQBrush << "Other value:" << i;

What are the "<<" operators doing in here ? Are they putting the string into the function ? And is it allowed in c++ syntax or does it only work in Qt (because the docs talk about QtDebugMsg too)

Comment: Why would you think it isn't allowed in C++?  If it were not allowed in C++, the compiler would give you an error, no?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there was some specific definition of the operator in Qt which was not there in the libraries of c++ and hence it wouldn't work.

Comment: A side note, qDebug is more or less using the same syntax as cout but it can handle the Qt classes better. (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having this syntax(`qDebug` with empty braces) it [returns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug) `QDebug` object which has an `operator<<` [overloaded](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt) and each time the operator finishes it returns a reference to the `QDebug` object so you can chain operations.

---

`qDebug` is a macro which is defined as:

```
QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
```

So if you write `qDebug` it gets replaced with the line above but `QMessageLogger::debug` is a function, not a field so you can't access it this fashion. The correct way to use a function is, obviously, add `()` to it. So we write `qDebug()` and after the macro get expanded we get:

```
QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug()
```

Which means: create a temporary object of type `QMessageLogger` and call a `debug` method on it. What is the `debug` method? Here it is: `QDebug debug() const;`. So the `qDebug()` line gives us a temporary object of `QDebug` type.

Then on this temporary object we call an `operator<<`(which one will be used depends on the parameter type).

Comment: I read about operator overloading but in their examples, they dont use "()" at the end of objects for which the operator is overloaded. Why is the bracket present here?

Comment: Thanks. Is this information available in the documentation present in QtCreator ?

Comment: @lisbeth, I doubt it. You can always check the source code, though. I checked it [there](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qlogging.h.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a stream operator.

> Output streams use the insertion (<<) operator for standard types. You can also overload the << operator for your own classes.

Here are the MSDN docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx